# processing special cases in python using sys.exit vs raise SomeError

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I'm writing a somewhat small python program and am concerned about the way I handle exceptions in my class methods and other functions.
To be more precise, I'm trying to think over all the pros and cons of using `sys.exit` (aka `raise SystemExit`) vs `raise AppropriateError`.
For instance, let's say, I've got the following function that prints the contents of a text file:

```
def print_lines(path_to_file):
    with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            print(line)
```

It's reasonable to check if the file provided to the function actually exists, so one way to do this is:

```
import sys
import os


def print_lines(path_to_file):
    if os.path.isfile(path_to_file):
        with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                print(line)
    else:
        sys.exit('Error: file not found')
```

Another way would be to `raise FileNotFoundError` which will then be intercepted and appropriately handled somewhere outside the function. At the first blush, it seems like using `sys.exit` saves you the trouble of writing additional lines of code (namely, the try-except-else block) and thus seems to be the way to go. So my question is:
in cases like that, when do you have to go for the sys.exit and when would it be better to raise an appropriate exception/error?

Comment: If you read the docu from the sys module you'll see that, in the end sys.exit only raises the `SystemExit` exception. So imo raising a proper exception is the better way to do it.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis well, yes, I know that but what if I want my code to stop if some condition is not satisfied? For example, if the print_lines function can't find a file.

Comment: Let's say you already know that this is something which is likely to happen, then I'd still use an exception and raise it with a line which tells to user what happened and how to proceed.
In the end if file is not there the script will stop working one way or the other. The good thing with exceptions is, that you can handle them and if you raise one every one who is reading your code later, will see that this is an **exception** and most likely not wanted to happen. 
If you say `sys.exit` one could think that is ok for the program and is something that could happen and is not a problem.